# How to find out Azure resources using ResourceGUID from an Azure invoice

Tags: azure

I have an Azure invoice from Microsoft sponsorship. In that, I can see the details of the usage of Azure services using an identifier called "ResourceGuid". Is it possible to find out the resources in the Azure console using the identifier "ResourceGuid"?

I've checked the normal resource pages and couldn't find a mapping between the identifier in the invoice and the details in the Azure console. Is there a possible way?

Comment: Could you maybe share a bit more on what your data/report looks like? I have resource IDs and subscription GUIDs but no resource GUIDs.

Comment: We've had the same problem; there is no 1:1 mapping between ResourceGUID and resource ID ([see this previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515992/how-to-get-resource-name-from-azure-resource-guid))